# add new row to server-side asp script table

Tags: asp-classic

I have a table which contains row and column. Is there any way that the user can click on the button and the initial table table can add on a new row to the created script? Below is my code for initial table.

```
    <form name=form1 method=POST action=add.asp>
    <table width="40%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" >
    <tr>
    <td height="30" bgcolor="#004080">&nbsp;<b><font color="#ffffff" size="2" face="Verdana">product</font></b></td>
    <td bgcolor="#dfefff">
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td height="30" bgcolor="#004080">&nbsp;<b><font color="#ffffff" size="2" face="Verdana">quantity</font></b></td>
    <td bgcolor="#dfefff">
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td height="30" bgcolor="#004080">&nbsp;<b><font color="#ffffff" size="2" face="Verdana">brand</font></b></td>
    <td bgcolor="#dfefff">
    </td>
    </tr>

    </table>
    <P><INPUT NAME="name" TYPE="reset" VALUE="Clear">
    <INPUT NAME="name1" TYPE="submit" VALUE="Submit">

    </form>
```

This is the view of my initial table.

```
    | product  |       |
    | quantity |       |
    | brand    |       |
```

Is there any way could let the user can click on the button on the web page and the asp script can auto add on  for new row and column in the asp script so that the asp script will become

```
    <form name=form1 method=POST action=add.asp>
    <table width="40%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" >
    <tr>
    <td height="30" bgcolor="#004080">&nbsp;<b><font color="#ffffff" size="2" face="Verdana">product</font></b></td>
    <td bgcolor="#dfefff">
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td height="30" bgcolor="#004080">&nbsp;<b><font color="#ffffff" size="2" face="Verdana">quantity</font></b></td>
    <td bgcolor="#dfefff">
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td height="30" bgcolor="#004080">&nbsp;<b><font color="#ffffff" size="2" face="Verdana">brand</font></b></td>
    <td bgcolor="#dfefff">
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td height="30" bgcolor="#004080">&nbsp;<b><font color="#ffffff" size="2" face="Verdana"></font></b></td>
    <td bgcolor="#dfefff">
    </td>
    </tr>

    </table>
    <P><INPUT NAME="name" TYPE="reset" VALUE="Clear">
    <INPUT NAME="name1" TYPE="submit" VALUE="Submit">

    </form>

    | product  |       |
    | quantity |       |
    | brand    |       |
    |          |       |
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the fourth row to appear when the button is pressed then all you need to do is put a conditional statement around your fourth row - ie

```
<% If request.form("name1") <> "" then %>    
<tr>
<td height="30" bgcolor="#004080">&nbsp;<b><font color="#ffffff" size="2" face="Verdana"></font></b></td>
<td bgcolor="#dfefff">
</td>
</tr>
<% End If %>
```

Obviously though the new row would disappear when you reload the page.  Is this all you want or do you want your changes to be preserved for future users.

NB, I think your second code sample is missing an opening  tag for the fourth row

Comment: Hi John, ya, the function that I needed is to do preserved for future usage. I needed the code can auto add on new row and column on the server-side script whenever the user want to add on new data requirement as they click on the button.

Comment: In that case you need code which writes to a file or a database - probably a database if we're talking about multiple table rows.  There are plenty of tutorials on the internet for both, here are some links to point you in the right direction. http://www.codefixer.com/tutorials/form_to_database.asp http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_ref_filesystem.asp http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_ref_textstream.asp